# Alternative to Group by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Colummn1             Column2
----------------------------                             
5                    24            
5                    20
5                    13
----------------------------
2                     3
----------------------------
3                    25
----------------------------
1                     4
----------------------------
2                     6
2                    42
----------------------------
5                    23
5                    10
----------------------------
```

Output should be

```
5       57
2       3
3       25
1       4
2       48
5       33
```

I have two columns. I want to sum the elements of second column when the values of column 1 are same and consecutive. ie I dont want the grouped sum to contain sum of both segments of 5.

I know how to use Group by clause bit that would aggregate the two segments. Please help me write SQL query for this .

Comment: you might need to show the data that you have and the result that you want. Currently your question and sample data doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please can you give us sample data and sample output? That will help alot.

Comment: SQL does not work that way - it does not guarantee any particular order. You need one more column which can be used for ORDER BY

Comment: "Consecutive" based on what?

Comment: Given the requirements of the query, and the need to group by not only by column value, but proximity as well, it appears as if your table is missing another key or field.  Do the rows have an additional foreign key, sequence value, or insert date you can add to the group by?